# Preserve cut potatoes

Tags: food-preservation, potatoes

I am going to cut some potatoes tonight for a dish I am going to make tomorrow. Will keeping the cut pieces in water immediately after cutting preserve them? There are suggestions at other websites that say adding some lime juice to the water will help. Has anyone had experience preserving potatoes?

Comment: Keeping the potatoes in water will cause some of the starch to leak out. Just something to bear in mind. Can either be positive or negative, depending on the dish, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty normal in many cultures to prepare vegetables for the evening meal in the morning, or even the day before. This has a long recorded history, at least to Roman times

Typically, vegetables that [brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browning_%28food_process%29) badly in that 24 hour period are either stored under water, or coated with a suitable dilute acidic solution (orange, lemon, or lime juice)

Cut potatoes stored underwater do not seem to suffer any detrimental effect over a 12 to 24 hour period. There will most likely be some starch and other nutrient loss to the water, but not to a level that anyone notices

Comment: I tried your advice and it worked! I put cut potatoes in water with a table spoon or so of lime juice.

Answer (score 1):

Sliced potatoes can be stored immersed in only tap water for several days without browning.

It helps to rinse the potatoes several times before storing.

I used to do this regularly at a restaurant where we served a pizza with thinly sliced potatoes on it.

Comment: "Several days" and "sliced" make me wary - you could be skirting "unsafe" here as far as food safety goes.

Answer (score 0):

It should be stored in a covered bowl with water (unsalted water) as I found through.

Don't know much about adding lime juice, but if it is stored with salted water, those potatoes cannot be prepared for a dish anymore.